# Gulp throwing error when running gulp images

Tags: imagemagick, gulp, graphicsmagick

I am unable to run gulp images.

This is what I have installed on my computer:

```
    ├── async@0.9.2
    ├── bower@1.3.12
    ├── browser-sync@2.1.6
    ├── chai@1.10.0
    ├── colors@1.1.2
    ├── glob@4.5.3
    ├── glob-all@3.0.1
    ├── gulp@3.9.0
    ├── gulp-changed@1.3.0
    ├── gulp-clean@0.3.1
    ├── gulp-compass@2.0.4
    ├── gulp-concat@2.5.2
    ├── gulp-flatten@0.0.4
    ├── gulp-gm@0.0.7
    ├── gulp-jsonminify@1.0.0
    ├── gulp-plumber@0.6.6
    ├── gulp-rename@1.2.2
    ├── gulp-template-compile@0.2.1
    ├── gulp-uglifyjs@0.6.2
    ├── imagemin-jpegoptim@4.0.0
    ├── imagemin-optipng@4.3.0
    ├── imagemin-pngquant@4.2.0
    ├── js-yaml@3.4.2
    ├── lodash@3.10.1
    ├── merge-stream@0.1.8
    ├── mocha@2.3.2
    ├── run-sequence@1.0.2
    └── should@4.6.5
```

And this is the error that gets flagged when I run gulp images:

```
Invalid image: /###/card/6997479627_922084ec63-card.jpg
[11:54:10] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error in plugin 'gulp-gm'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling gulp, graphicsmagick, and imagemagick but it still flags the error.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the error in `gulp-gm` plugin? I'm not familiar with this gm module, but I have a feeling there's a missing system library/delegate that just needs to be installed independently of `gulp`.

Answer (score 0):

I would install the latest version of gulp-gm, image manipulation with GraphicsMagick for gulp.